# VLC and other Multi Media Problems

Tags: multimedia, video-player

I've tried numerous free multimedia applications on Ubuntu and I get the same result when I watch one of my movies off my other hard drive. It always ends up full screening with a stuck image in the middle, while VLC ends up looking pitch black. On the bottom of my question you'll find two pictures demonstrating my issue.

I've looked all over the web for this issue and I'm wondering if anyone is experiencing the same problems. It may have to do with my dual monitor setup. I've also tried adding and re adding the repositories but it seems to be doing the same repetitive thing for over a month now. Do i need to reinstall the whole system or what?

Could anyone be of any help here? Thank you, MrMagu.

---

#### My Xorg Conf File

```
 nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 304.37  (buildd@allspice)  Sun Sep  9 05:59:26 UTC 2012


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE247"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc VE247"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1500"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro FX 1500"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-1: 1920x1080 +1920+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050 +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x960 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x960_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_70 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select @1920x720 +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050 +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x960 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x960_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_70 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-1: 1920x1080 +1920+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080 +0+0, DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0; DFP-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050 +0+0; DFP-0: 1680x1050_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900 +0+0; DFP-0: 1440x900_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x1024_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x960 +0+0; DFP-0: 1280x960_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864 +0+0; DFP-0: 1152x864_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_70 +0+0; DFP-0: 1024x768_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_60 +0+0; DFP-0: 800x600_56 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_75 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_72 +0+0; DFP-0: 640x480_60 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Mouse Remap"
        MatchProduct "Saitek Cyborg R.A.T.7 Mouse"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "ButtonMapping" "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0"
EndSection
```

#### Pictures

- [picture #1](http://tinypic.com/r/34o7j1h/6)
- [picture #2 - VLC](http://tinypic.com/r/3rn20/6)